# ASP.NET Web Forms Routing and paths to js files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, routes, relative-path

I am working on an ASP.NET Web Forms project that make use of Routing.
I have two routing situations:

http://mywebsite.com/**section**

http://mywebsite.com/**section**/**subsection**

My js files are stored in a /js folder in the root of the project.
Fact is, when I load /section page everything works fine, the js are loaded correctly. When I load /section/subsection page the js are not loaded and actually the path appear to be something like

http://www.mywebsite.com/**section**/file.js

I have already tried to put a slash before the name of the js folder or even to use a server side ResolveUrl function like

```
<script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/file.js")%>'></script>
```

In this case file.js il loaded correctly; anyway if file.js contains calls to an external js file, the latter is not loaded (its path is always in the form of /**section**/externalfile.js).

Adding the following line to the Global.asax

```
routes.Ignore("{*allfiles}", new { allfiles = @".*\.(css|js|gif|jpg|png)" });
```

did not solve the problem either.

The most surprising thing is the fact that, for instance, image or CSS files are loaded correctly even with a normal link like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.theme.css" media="all" />
```

Is there anyone who has an idea of how solving this issue ?

**Edit**: The master page of my project calls a cutom.js file (which is loaded correctly). This file contains for instance the following call to superfish.min.js:

```
Modernizr.load([{
 load: kopa_variable.url.template_directory_uri + 'js/superfish.min.js',
 complete: function() {
  $('.top-menu').superfish({});
 }
}]);
```

Comment: Can you give an example from `file.js` that calls an external js file?

Comment: The master page of my project calls a cutom.js file (which is loaded correctly). This file contains for instance the following call to superfish.min.js: Modernizr.load([
  {
    load: kopa_variable.url.template_directory_uri + 'js/superfish.min.js',
    complete: function () {

        //Main menu
        $('.top-menu').superfish({
        });
    }
  }
]); Of course I could change every 'js/ call in all of my javascript files. I am looking for a solution anyway that allows me to solve the problem without editing these files.

Comment: Most likely, the value `kopa_variable.url.template_directory_uri` has causes the issue. You could change that into something static, e.g. `load: '/js/superfish.min.js'`.